# Error when aggregating in linq query

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

I want to output linq results to an IEnumerable list but I get a cast error:

```
IEnumerable<vwHour> Total = (from p in vwHours.Where(ph => ph.UserName == UserName())
                                 group p by p.Date into g
                                 select new {Date = g.Key.Value.ToString("mm/dd/yy"), Total = g.Sum(p => p.Hours),});
```

Error Message:

```
Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<UI.Models.vwHour>'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)
```

Am I missing anything here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to put a list of an anonymous type into a variable for a list of `vwHour`.

If you wanted to return a list of an anonymous type, you can simply change the variable type to `var`:

```
var Total = (  ...
```

If you really want this query to return a list of `vwHour`, you need to modify the `select`:

```
select new vwHour {  ...
```

But this requires that vwHour has a `Total` property and a `string Date` property. But we can see from the `group by` and `select` clauses that your `vwHour` type has already a `Date` property which seems to be a `Nullable<DateTime>`. So there is no way the `select` will work if you change it to create `vwHour`s.

If your vwHour class is something like this:

```
class vwHour
{
    public object UserName { get; set; }
    public DateTime? Date { get; set; }
    public int Hours { get; set; }
}
```

Then this would work:

```
IEnumerable<vwHour> Total = 
    (from p in vwHours.Where(ph => ph.UserName == UserName())
     group p by p.Date into g
     select new vwHour { Date = g.Key, Hours = g.Sum(p => p.Hours), });
```

Comment: @user793468: The () is optional in the object initializer syntax. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb384062.aspx

Answer (score 2):

```
IEnumerable<vwHour> Total = (from p in vwHours.Where(ph => ph.UserName == UserName())
                             group p by p.Date into g
                             select new vwHour(){ //<----
                                          Date = g.Key.Value.ToString("mm/dd/yy"), 
                                          Total = g.Sum(p => p.Hours)
                                        });
```